# Swift 3 - Disable & enable segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segmentedcontrol

I've got two table views and I switch between them by selecting a segmented control. I also got a search controller with a search bar. When I select the search bar, the segmented control should be disabled, so that you can't select the second table view. When I click on the cancel button in the search bar, the segmented control should be activated again. But this doesn't work, the segmented control stays disabled. 
When I select a table view cell and return to this view controller, then the segmented control is enabled again. But I want it to be enabled when I press the cancel button.
My code looks as follows:

```
   func deactivateSegment() {
    segmentedController.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 1)
}

func activateSegment() {
    segmentedController.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
}


extension SegmentedTableController: UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    deactivateSegment()
    if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "update_view"), object: rumList, userInfo: nil)
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    KCFABManager.defaultInstance().hide()
    deactivateSegment()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    KCFABManager.defaultInstance().show()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "update_view"), object: self.rumList, userInfo: nil)

   activateSegment()
}
}
```

I also tried it with `segmentedController.isEnabled = false (&true)`
and `segmentedController.isUserInteractionEnabled = false (&true)`
but that also doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove this `deactivateSegment()` in `updateSearchResults `

Comment: Yeah, that did it, thanks! I removed deactivate from updateSearchResults, and now it works as I want.

Comment: welcome .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `deactivateSegment()` in the delegate method of `updateSearchResults`

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
   // deactivateSegment()
  if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
```

else do like

```
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
        activateSegment()
    } else {
        deactivateSegment()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "update_view"), object: rumList, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```